# Displaying paused/static analogue clock

Tags: android

My application needs to display the time. Rather then displaying time as 11:00 I am wondering whether it is possible to have to have static/paused/stopped analogue clock showing 11' o clock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `AnalogClock` widget, but it shows the current time. There is no way to pause or stop it, because there is no way to pause or stop time in the real world.

You may be able to subclass it or clone it to achieve your desired results. Or, you can draw one yourself using the `Canvas`.

Comment: I have found DigitalClock on Android.git.kernel.org. Is AnalogClock open source? If so, where would that be defined?

It doesn't look like it would hard to create my own version with stopped time. I would rather not go the route of drawing myself, being back end developer I have never done anything to do with graphics.

Comment: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AnalogClock.java&q=package:android%20AnalogClock&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc